# Make JS call to custom Craft CMS plugin

Tags: yii2, craftcms

I'm trying to build a custom plugin for Craft CMS in which I have a button.
I have managed to create the plugin and a Widget. I can add CSS and JS for the widget.
Now I would like to make a call with JS when I click on the button.
This call needs to be made to a function in the plugin.

I don't understand where I can write the function I want to execute when calling for a JS file.
I tried finding other plugins that have a similar functionality but I can't find any which do this exact thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make an 'action controller method' inside your plugin that your JS can 'hit' using AJAX.

Info on CraftCMS Action Controller Methods can be found here:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/controllers.html#actions